# CFLAGS in configure script

Tags: c, makefile, configure, autogen

I usually use an IDE whenever I write my own code. I don't know very much about make, configure scripts, etc.

I'm working on a large and complicated existing project now, and the steps to build are:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

I wrote my own C files and added them to Makefile.am. I then repeat this process to build.

Everything is fine, except for one thing. I want to build without any compiler options like -Wall. I was told that using CFLAGS like this would give me what I want:

```
./configure CFLAGS=-O0
```

It doesn't seem to work, because the compiler still uses the -Wall option. I can manually remove all occurances of -Wall from the CFLAGS="..." in the configure script. This is annoying but it works. But then when I execute

```
./autogen.sh
```

The configure script is reset with all of the -Walls (and other CLFAGS I don't want) back in their original places. (I'm not sure but I think I have to run autogen.sh every time I add new files to Makefile.am.)

Is there a better way deal with this?

Comment: Why haven't you fixed your code so that it compiles silently with `-Wall`?  Is it safe to use, in fact, when there are warnings from `-Wall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way might be to do it when actually *building*, using `make`:

```
make CFLAGS=-O0
```

That's only temporary for that build though, it won't be permanent.

Comment: Thanks, this helped but now I have another problem. Apparently there is still an option 'Wl,-soname' which I also need to disable somehow. Have any idea how to disable this option?

Comment: @JamesMiller That looks like a linker flags, which is `LDFLAGS`

Answer (score 4):

Doing a

```
./configure --help
```

shows

```
Some influential environment variables: ...
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
```

The better approach is

```
env CFLAGS="-O0" ./configure
```

Then a simple

```
make
```

does as you expect.  This is helpful to set other compile flags.

Comment: The advice is generally the other way around.  Rather than `CFLAGS=-O0 ./configure`, it's better to do `./configure CFLAGS=-O0`, because in that case the `./configure` script will record the fact that that variable was set, and ensure it's set again if you do `./config.status --recheck`. (It sounds as if this isn't the OP's problem, though)